# UITableView sorting by rank

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sorting, floating-point

I have got an plist with an object it is a number with rank. I want to sort by the value of the float. From the biggest number to the lowest. And I dont know how to write the function.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sort the array you get from your plist by the rank

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"your rank key"
                                                                   ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptor release];
```

**Do it before you pass the array to the TableView**

Good luck

Comment: Just this I have to change: sortUsingDescriptors to sortedArrayUsingDescriptors. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you..

use  NSSortDescriptor for sorting the values for acending or decending..